# Cannot run program using system() in R

Tags: r, macos, command-line

I am trying to run `computeMatrix` from the package [deepTools](https://deeptools.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html) in a R script using `system()`.

The following command gets this error message.

`system('computeMatrix --help')`

> sh: computeMatrix: command not found 
> Warning message: 
> In system("computeMatrix --help") : error in running command

However, if I run the same command in the terminal everthing works fine.

---

`sessionInfo()`

> R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
> Running under: macOS Big Sur 10.16 
> Matrix products: default 
> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

Comment: When running a command in the terminal, it runs inside an interactive shell. This is *very* different from running the command directly — mostly because it loads configuration files for the shell, which are often responsible for setting environment variables such as `PATH`, which changes how the shell finds executables.

Comment: Is there an easy way to tell R where to look for the program or initializing it in the same way in R as in the terminal?

Comment: Open a terminal window, type `which computeMatrix`, copy the full path to the executable into your `system` command.

Comment: @samu You can execute a command in a subshell. But generally you don’t want to do that; instead, you want the `PATH` to be set correctly *when launching R*. So: how is R launched?

Comment: @user12728748 That’s a very bad idea. Don’t hard-code absolut paths, pretty much ever (`/usr/bin/env` and `/bin/sh` are two of the very few exceptions). Doing so will only cause issues maintaining the code and making it runnable on other systems (or the same system in the future).

Comment: OK, I agree it is kind of a dirty fix... maybe define an environment variable in your code and pass that to the system command, e.g. `Sys.sentenv(DEEPTOOLS_DIR="/data/anaconda/envs/python3.6/bin/"); system("$DEEPTOOLS_DIR/computeMatrix -help")` (and pass the variable to your program, not to hardcode it)

Comment: I'm guessing that the issue is a system path ... I suggest you find where it is located, add that directory to `PATH` in the OS itself, and then to make sure that R see the change ... log out, log back in, start a fresh R/RStudio, and see if you see the new directory within `Sys.getenv("PATH")`.

Comment: @r2evans Unfortunately macOS doesn’t really support systemwise environment variables any more. You were able to configure them with launchctl until a few years ago, but under recent versions of macOS, applications launched via the GUI no longer inherit them.

Comment: Setting `Sys.setenv(PATH = "/Users/samuel/anaconda3/bin/")` (path where the programm was installed) in the beginning of my script solved the problem.

Comment: @samu Sure, but that’s *also* just hard-coding the path and, as noted in a previous comment, that’s a very bad idea.

Comment: @KonradRudolph so do you know how I can set the path correctly when launching R? And is it a problem that I used anaconda to install the package but do not use anaconda to install other R packages in general?

Comment: @samu I’ve found that using Conda with R packages can lead to issues. But this shouldn’t be the problem here. Setting the path for R depends on how R is launched, see previous comments.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I now launched RStudio from the terminal in the environment in which I installed the program and it works fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was run in Ubuntu 20.04.
The recommended way of running system commands is with `system2`, not `system`. The arguments are passed in a vector, `args`. In this case `args` is a length 1 vector but if there are more than one argument, pass them as

```
args <- c("arg1", "arg2", etc)
```

This command worked as expected.

```
cmd <- "computeMatrix"
args <- "--version"
system2(cmd, args)
#computeMatrix 3.3.2

sessionInfo()
#R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
#Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
#Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
#
#Matrix products: default
#BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
#LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0
#
#locale:
# [1] LC_CTYPE=pt_PT.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
# [3] LC_TIME=pt_PT.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=pt_PT.UTF-8    
# [5] LC_MONETARY=pt_PT.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pt_PT.UTF-8   
# [7] LC_PAPER=pt_PT.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
# [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
#[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=pt_PT.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

#attached base packages:
#[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#
#loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#[1] compiler_4.0.4
```